# Speed up json loading

Tags: javascript, json, variables, delay

I'm working with some local json files but I'm having some problems with the loading speed. My server is just a little webserver made with python and I usually use it for trying my javascript code.
My script works only with Firefox and I have to put a delay of 60000 ms (or use firebug). 
The script is:

```
function geisson()
{
var iabile = new XMLHttpRequest();

iabile.open("GET", "longanocard.json", true);
iabile.send(null);


PerdiTempo(60000);

var objectjson = {};
var arrayCards= []; //creazione dell'array che conterrà le cards


objectson = JSON.parse(iabile.responseText);

arrayCards = objectson.cards;
//alert(arrayCards[0].__guid__.toSource());


var qwerty = arrayCards[0].__guid__;

var mela = "http://www.airpim.com/png/public/card/" + qwerty + "?width=292";    


document.location = mela;
//windows.location.href= mela;
}
```

PerdiTempo is the function I use for the delay:

```
function PerdiTempo(ms)
{
ms += new Date().getTime();
while (new Date() < ms){}
}
```

How can I speed up the loading of the file longanocard.json? Why the delay doesn't work with other browsers?

Comment: waiting the response in this way is awful. You should work with a callback, checking the response status at `onreadystatechange` event

Comment: You should never code a delay with a loop like that because the browser won't repaint until the JS code finishes so from the user's point of view the browser will have locked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really avoid to wait an asynchronous response in that way (how do you know exactly how much seconds delay the JSON parsing?), using instead the `onreadystatechange` event for your request

```
function geisson() {

    var iabile = new XMLHttpRequest();

    iabile.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(iabile.readyState === 4 && iabile.status === 200) {
            var objectjson = {};
            var arrayCards= []; //creazione dell'array che conterrà le cards
            objectson = JSON.parse(iabile.responseText);

            ...
            /* codice restante qui */

        }
    }
    iabile.open("GET", "longanocard.json", true);
    iabile.send(null);

}
```